# Appropriate forgot password approach using SMS Android

Tags: android, password-recovery

Which is the best procedure to follow in recovering the forgotten password of a user using SMS approach?
In other words, what should I send and retrieve from the database?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be able to, because you shouldn't know their password either.  You should only know the salted hash of their password, which is sufficient to check if they knew it but not require you to actually tell them it.

You should also never send a password by SMS.  It isn't secure, and can be read by any app on the phone.  What would be acceptable is to send a link or confirmation code via SMS that would allow the user to reset his password to a new password, provided that he had some other info about the account (such as the username, or a cookie matching the one that made the request for reset).

You should never send all the info needed to reset the account by SMS.  In other words, don't send the username and password/reset code both by SMS, because then if his SMS is compromised the account is compromised.